# simplepie not parsing google news rss feed

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

This code works perfectly with any other rss feed but not with google news feeds. I do not know what I am doing wrong, I think it's some bug.
I keep getting this error when I try to read google news feeds

`This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing at line 1, column 61`

For example if we try the `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds` feeds it works nicely, but not with google news feeds. Can some one give me a hint?

```
<?php

    //get the simplepie library
    require_once('simplepie.inc');

    //grab the feed
    $feed = new SimplePie();

    $feed->set_feed_url("http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=us&q=austria&ie=UTF-8&output=rss");
    $feed->force_feed(true);
    //$feed->encode_instead_of_strip(true);


    //enable caching
    $feed->enable_cache(true);

    //provide the caching folder
    $feed->set_cache_location('cache');

    //set the amount of seconds you want to cache the feed
    $feed->set_cache_duration(1800);

    //init the process
    $feed->init();

    //let simplepie handle the content type (atom, RSS...)
    $feed->handle_content_type();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>simple</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

    <h1>News Finder</h1>

    <?php if ($feed->error): ?>
      <p><?php echo $feed->error; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>

        <div class="chunk">

            <h4 style="background:url(<?php $feed = $item->get_feed(); echo $feed->get_favicon(); ?>) no-repeat; text-indent: 25px; margin: 0 0 10px;"><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h4>

            <p class="footnote">Source: <a href="<?php $feed = $item->get_feed(); echo $feed->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php $feed = $item->get_feed(); echo $feed->get_title(); ?></a> | <?php echo $item->get_date('j M Y | g:i a T'); ?></p>



        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


</div>
```

Comment: I believe I have found the issue. It is a problem with my hosting company[Rackspace]. When I tried it on a different hosting account I have with another company, it worked like a charm. Thanks @Ryan for coming and helping out. Take care

Comment: I'm facing pretty much the same issue. Could you tell me what exactly was the problem with your host?

Comment: Yes, please tell us what the problem of your host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're using [SimplePie 1.2.1](http://simplepie.org/), 1.2 had a bug with URL parsing which can cause this type of error.

(I'm also the SimplePie lead developer, so feel free to shoot questions straight to my email)

If you are using 1.2.1, it would appear that this is a manifestation of [bug #162](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues/162) which is currently unconfirmed. I'll take an indepth look into this, but it appears to definitely be an error in SimplePie, not in your code.

(I'll also post back here with why this is occurring for the curious amongst you.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I am using 1.2.1 downloaded today. That's the code I have which has worked for every feed such as `stackoverflow.com/feed` etc.. except for google news feeds. I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about SimplePie, however, the simple way in your case might be just SimpleXML:

```
$url = "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=us&q=austria&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&biw=1920&bih=973&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss";
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo $feed->channel->title, "\n<", $feed->channel->link, ">\n\n";

foreach($feed->channel->item as $item)
{
    echo "* $item->title\n  <$item->link>\n";
}
```

SimpleXML is normally directly available with PHP, you don't need to install any library or so.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xmq3Nx)

Comment: thanks hakre, I tried your script on my server and it seems to not work. Is there some requirement?

Comment: SimpleXML is fine as long as you know that the feed will conform to RSS/Atom. The problem is, the majority of feeds on the internet do not.

SimplePie is really, at its heart, a normalisation layer on SimpleXML.

Comment: @Ryan McCue: SimpleXML does not focus that much on feeds specifically as SimplePie does, so it's not really an alternative, it just worked for the Feed in question.

Answer (score 0):

For Google News feed uses :

```
$feed->set_raw_data(file_get_contents($rssurl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a note here for others that think the above answer doesn't work. If your getting a null on item title, check the feed source, it may not be anything wrong with your simplepie or script, but your browser setting it to null because of html code within the title item tags.

Comment: "above answer" is meaningless because answers can be sorted by date, by votes, or by activity. Please use a link to the answer or use the answer's author name.