# Simplepie is breaking when i'm on a live server compare when i'm working on localhost(xampp)

Tags: php, xml-parsing, webserver, hosting, simplepie

I get this error

```
This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 35, column 44
```

when I'm doing this one on my live server, but when I try to run SimplePie on localhost(xampp), I can't see that error. I'm using this feed url `http://splashpage.mtv.com/feed/` on both live server and on my localhost(xampp). Do I need to enable something on my server? I'm using SimplePie version 1.3.
Please help me on this matter.

By the way, I saw this on another thread: [simplepie not parsing google news rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663744/simplepie-not-parsing-google-news-rss-feed) and one of the person who asked told something that it was about his hosting/server.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Class Simplepie needs at least 64M! Try modifying php.ini with that value: **memory_limit = 64M**

Comment: The error is not about Memory Allocation so extending into 64M is not applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `rss` tag in the feed is not well-formed:

```
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"xmlns:advertorial="http://wordpress.mtvn.com/plugins/MTVNAdvertorials" >
```

A space is missing before the `xmlns:advertorial` attribute.

Try using a more lenient XML parser - maybe simplexml (http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or the XML Parser (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) will work.

Comment: But why is it when I try it on my localhost it works perfectly, only when I uploaded this one on my live server came up this kind of error. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Maybe you use different versions of SimplePie on your local machine and your live site.

Comment: I'm using the same version and that is 1.3.

Comment: Are you using different PHP versions?

Comment: Xampp PHP Version =  5.3.5

My live PHP Version = 5.2.9

Would that matter?

Comment: Yes, I think it matters. Can you upgrade your live PHP (or downgrade your XAMPP)?

Comment: Also download the rss feed locally and on your server and compare them byte-by-byte. There might be an encoding problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19922/discussion-between-botond-balazs-and-elson-solano)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this one by just this one

```
$SimplePieFeed = new SimplePie();
$SimplePieFeed->set_feed_url("http://splashpage.mtv.com/feed/");
$SimplePieFeed->enable_cache(true);
$SimplePieFeed->enable_order_by_date(true);
$success = $SimplePieFeed->init();
$SimplePieFeed->handle_content_type();
```

I just added `$SimplePieFeed->enable_cache(true);`

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Now *this* is weird. How on earth would caching affect the validity of the XML? Glad you could solve it though.

Comment: Right! Super weird! I even don't know why. If anyone would clear why this is happening then that would be awesome!